# PHP/MySQLi form SQL Syntax Error - Suggestions, Answers, or Advice on why it's not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, syntax

I've seen this question asked many times and I've tried different solutions without any luck, so here goes: I am creating a form that stores usernames and passwords without validation for the moment (for testing and learning). I'm using var_dump($_POST); and so I can see that values are being inputted from the html form. I'm not certain what I am doing wrong and appreciate any advice, answers, and suggestions. Thanks in advance!

> array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "rafel" ["password"]=> string(6) "rafael" }
>
> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username', 'password') VALUES ('rafel', 'rafael')' at line 1

my php is as follows:

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST); 
$server_name = "*******";
$admin_name = "********";
$root_password = "********";
$database_name = "myDBPDO";
$table_name = "myguests";
$connect = mysql_connect($server_name, $admin_name, $root_password); 

if (!'connect') {die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error());} 

mysql_select_db($database_name, $connect); 

if(isset($_POST['username'])) 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
if(empty($username)) $username = 'heybardly'; 

if(isset($_POST['password'])) 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if(empty($password)) $password = 'monochrome1724';

$user_info = "INSERT INTO table_name ('username', 'password') VALUES ('$username', '$password')"; 
if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) {die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}

echo "Your information was added to the database.";
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($connect);
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

my HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cinnamon RP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstylesheet.css">
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="form.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="username">
Email:<input type="text" name="password">
Submit<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo this query "INSERT INTO table_name ('username', 'password') VALUES ('$username', '$password')" and after that copy this query and try in phpmyadmin check what's going wrong.......you get perfect solution

Comment: Note: If you are still learning, please don't learn using the `mysql_*()` functions. They are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. If you are learning, start with `mysqli_*` or PDO and do it the right way.

Comment: ...and even if you're not - but I suppose we're all still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `quotes` you have to use `backtick` in your `column and table name`

```
 $user_info = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')";
```

> NOTE:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or pdo

Don't store plain password into database

check http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion worked and I was able to input the data, which was all I wanted for this form, no actual values will be used for it, though I will be creating a real form, and so your advice on PDO and password hashing is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use backtics instead of single quotes.This should be

```
$user_info = "INSERT INTO table_name (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
                                      ^        ^  ^        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from column names.

Advice on future coding...Start using PDO or Mysqli as mysql is deprecated.